# parted not recognizing loop device

Tags: parted, loop-device

I created a loop device with

```
$ truncate -s 20G test.img
$ losetup -fP ./test.img
$ losetup -a
/dev/loop0: [0032]:4051 (/tmp/test/test.img)
```

`lsblk` is able to see it just fine

```
$ test]# lsblk 
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0    20G  0 loop
...
```

Now I'd like to create partitions with `parted` on that device, however, `parted` is unable to detect `/dev/loop0`

```
$ parted -l
Model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI      boot, esp
 2      538MB   512GB  512GB               primary
```

Why is parted not detecting the loop device?

Updated

```
$ partprobe -s
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system).
/dev/nvme0n1: gpt partitions 1 2
```

```
$ mount
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8038444k,nr_inodes=2009611,mode=755,inode64)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/mapper/luksdev on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=2158)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,noatime,inode64)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1610492k,nr_inodes=402623,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

```
$ lsblk -lndp -o NAME
/dev/loop0
/dev/nvme0n1
```

Comment: Try the `partprobe` or `partprobe -P`

Comment: Didn't help and `partprobe` has no flag `-P`

Comment: `partbrobe -s` output?

Comment: Updated with the output

Comment: Mount output? May your /tmp tmpfs?

Comment: Why do you need `parted` to "detect" it? What keeps you from running `parted /dev/loop0`? or even `parted test.img` in the first place?

Comment: @K-attila- updated with the `mount` output.
@KamilMaciorowski because I have a script with a selection of possible devices and I would like to show it there as a option

Comment: Looks like your problem based on the tmpfs. How many memory do you have?

Comment: `lsblk -lndp -o NAME`? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: What happens when you create test image with ` dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=20G count=1` ?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski updated. 
@K-attila- I have now tried to create the image under ~/Downloads and it's the same problem, also the `dd` command results in the same

Comment: So what is the problem in taking the list from `lsblk -lndp -o NAME` in your script? Why do you need the list to come from `parted -l`?

Comment: [`parted -l` skips over loop](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=parted.git;a=blob;f=libparted/arch/linux.c;h=ccbba8656bc7ef0663aea6431bfb8873deccd0ef;hb=HEAD#l2304), ram, fd devices and handles dm- devices separately (if device mapper support is enabled).

Comment: @frostschutz right, thanks for the source!